# Hardware acceleration of color conversion and scaling using QSV with ffmpeg, libav

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, intel, libav

I used hardware decoding on an Intel processor using QuickSync based on this example.
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/qsv_decode.c

Then I use sws_scale to color convert from NV12 to YUV420. But is there a way to use hardware acceleration for this too?

some part of my code

```
//decoding frame
int32_t ret = avcodec_receive_frame(_context, _tmpFrame); //i got _tmpFrame->format == AV_PIX_FMT_QSV

//retrieve data from GPU to CPU
av_hwframe_transfer_data(_decFrame, _tmpFrame, 0); //i got _decFrame->format == AV_PIX_FMT_NV12

//...some code next
//init context
conversion = sws_getContext(_context->width, _context->height, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12,
                             _context->width,_context->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                             SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL,NULL,NULL);

//convert frame  (is Intel QuickSync used here)?
int32_t out_height = sws_scale(conversion, src_data, src_stride, 0, src_height, dst_data, dst_stride);
```

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you with some questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216220/2920861